# Python pip install missing module pkgutil

Tags: python, pip

I am getting my python pip from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/
and it is giving an error saying 
ImportError: No module named pkgutil

what are the dependencies I need before get-pip.py?

```
python get-pip.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 24, in <module>
    import pkgutil
ImportError: No module named pkgutil
```

Comment: 1. What Python version? (If it's 3.4+, why are you using `get-pip` instead of using `ensurepip`, or just letting the installer do it?) 2. How did you install it? (And, if the answer to 2 is "I'm using my OS/distro pre-installed Python", read the big red warning in the page you linked.)

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/pkgutil.html           according to this, the pkgutil should be in since python 2.3. Will try to download the lib .py file and try again

Comment: If you only answer a fraction of the questions you're asked, nobody can help you. Also, please edit the question to include important info, don't just put it in comments. I'm assuming you actually read the page you linked to. Are you actually using a Python 2.7 version before 2.7.9? If not, why are you running `get-pip.py`? If, say, it's because you're using a distro-supplied (or Apple-supplied) Python, you're doing the wrong thing, and we can explain why—but if you won't tell us anything about what you're using except that it's 2.7, all we can tell is that you must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using debian based system, Type the following commands:

1. `sudo apt-file search pkgfile`

   - The output of the above command will display a list of packages             containing the desired package.
   - Install from the list of packages suitable to your Python version using the following command.
2. `sudo apt-get install package-name<br/>`

**Note:** 
If `apt-file` is not currently installed on your system then install it first using `sudo apt-get install apt-file` command